# Converting dense matrix code to sparse matrix code

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, sparse-matrix

I'm trying to convert this code to use scipy sparse matrices as the real matrix is very large, but am having trouble with it. Please can anyone help?

```
import numpy as np
G = np.array([[0., 50., 50., 0.],
              [10., 0., 10., 0.],
              [0., 0., 0., 10.],
              [2., 0., 2., 0.]])
s = G.sum(axis=0)
m = np.minimum(G, 1).transpose()
sm = s * m
sm_rnorm = (sm / sm.sum(axis=0))
smm = sm * sm_rnorm
G += smm.transpose()
print(G)
```

I tried the following:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.sparse import csc_matrix
G = np.array([[0.,50.,50.,0.],
              [10.,0.,10.,0.],
              [0.,0.,0.,10.],
              [2.,0.,2.,0.]])
G = csc_matrix(G, dtype=np.float)
s = csc_matrix(G.sum(axis=0))
m = csc_matrix.minimum(G, 1).transpose()
sm = s * m
sm_rnorm = (sm / csc_matrix(sm.sum(axis=0)))
smm = sm * sm_rnorm
G += smm.transpose()
print(G)
```

...but get `ValueError: dimension mismatch`

Comment: *"When I tried converting the above,..."*  Show the code that you tried.

Comment: Yes, sparse matrix row or column sums are dense matrices.  In your example only 1 row is all 0s, and no columns.

Comment: what do you mean the sum is "converted back to dense"? you mean it should be zero in some elements? If so you have a singular matrix and the corresponding rows should be removed from the original matrix.

Comment: @hpaulj I don't see any all zero row! which row you are pointing to specifically?

Comment: I missed the last 10 on the 3rd row.

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser I've added my embarrassing attempt :)

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser it seems to make a difference when I run it without .transpose() I think np.minimum is an element-wise minimum.

Comment: Argh, you are correct!  I mistook it for `numpy.min(G, axis=1)`.  Nevermind!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran your dense code,

```
In [224]: G = np.array([[0., 50., 50., 0.],
     ...:               [10., 0., 10., 0.],
     ...:               [0., 0., 0., 10.],
     ...:               [2., 0., 2., 0.]])
     ...: s = G.sum(axis=0)
     ...: m = np.minimum(G, 1).transpose()
     ...: sm = s * m
     ...: sm_rnorm = (sm / sm.sum(axis=0))
     ...: smm = sm * sm_rnorm
     ...:               
In [225]: s
Out[225]: array([12., 50., 62., 10.])
In [226]: m
Out[226]: 
array([[0., 1., 0., 1.],
       [1., 0., 0., 0.],
       [1., 1., 0., 1.],
       [0., 0., 1., 0.]])
In [227]: sm
Out[227]: 
array([[ 0., 50.,  0., 10.],
       [12.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [12., 50.,  0., 10.],
       [ 0.,  0., 62.,  0.]])
```

and then started the sparse version:

```
In [192]: from scipy import sparse
In [228]: Gm = sparse.csr_matrix(G)
In [229]: Gm
Out[229]: 
<4x4 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 7 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
In [230]: s_m = Gm.sum(axis=0)
In [231]: s_m
Out[231]: matrix([[12., 50., 62., 10.]])
In [233]: m_m = Gm.minimum(1).T
In [234]: m_m.A
Out[234]: 
array([[0., 1., 0., 1.],
       [1., 0., 0., 0.],
       [1., 1., 0., 1.],
       [0., 0., 1., 0.]])
```

Oops:

```
In [236]: s_m * m_m
Out[236]: matrix([[112.,  74.,  10.,  74.]])
```

`*` if matrix multiplication for `np.matrix` and sparse matrix

```
In [237]: s.dot(m)
Out[237]: array([112.,  74.,  10.,  74.])
```

sparse matrix element wise multiplication:

```
In [242]: sm_m = m_m.multiply(s_m)
In [243]: sm_m.A
Out[243]: 
array([[ 0., 50.,  0., 10.],
       [12.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [12., 50.,  0., 10.],
       [ 0.,  0., 62.,  0.]])
```

now to match `sm_rnorm`:

```
In [244]: sm_m.sum(axis=0)
Out[244]: matrix([[ 24., 100.,  62.,  20.]])
In [250]: sm_m / sm_m.sum(axis=0)
Out[250]: 
matrix([[0. , 0.5, 0. , 0.5],
        [0.5, 0. , 0. , 0. ],
        [0.5, 0.5, 0. , 0.5],
        [0. , 0. , 1. , 0. ]])
```

`sparse/dense` works elementwise, but `sparse/sparse` has problems:

```
In [252]: sm_m / sparse.csr_matrix(sm_m.sum(axis=0))
----> 1 sm_m / sparse.csr_matrix(sm_m.sum(axis=0))
--> 576         return self._divide(other, true_divide=True)
    568             if true_divide and np.can_cast(self.dtype, np.float_):
ValueError: inconsistent shapes
```

I think this is a matrix division issue, but I'd dig further to be sure.

`sm_m.multiply(1 / sm_m.sum(axis=0))` gives a sparse matrix with the right values, but is slower (at least for this example).

`smm_m = sm_m.multiply( sm_m / sm_m.sum(axis=0))` matches `smm`.  And `Gm += smm_m` works.  Sparse `+=` doesn't raise an efficiency error because it doesn't change the sparsity.

So the key issue is keeping matrix multiplication and element multiplication straight (and the the corresponding divisions).

### w/ sklearn

`sklearn.utils.sparsefuncs` has some sparse utility functions

The above `sm_m` is `coo` format array (not sure why):

```
In [366]: sm_m
Out[366]: 
<4x4 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 7 stored elements in COOrdinate format>
In [367]: sm_m.A
Out[367]: 
array([[ 0., 50.,  0., 10.],
       [12.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [12., 50.,  0., 10.],
       [ 0.,  0., 62.,  0.]])
```

convert it to `csr`:

```
In [368]: sm_m1 = sm_m.tocsr()
In [369]: sm_m1
Out[369]: 
<4x4 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 7 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
```

derive the column scaling array:

```
In [370]: x = sm_m1.sum(axis=0)
In [371]: x
Out[371]: matrix([[ 24., 100.,  62.,  20.]])
In [372]: x = 1/x.A1      # .A1 makes a 1d array from np.matrix
```

apply scaling inplace:

```
In [373]: sklearn.utils.sparsefuncs.inplace_csr_column_scale(sm_m1,x)
In [374]: sm_m1.A
Out[374]: 
array([[0. , 0.5, 0. , 0.5],
       [0.5, 0. , 0. , 0. ],
       [0.5, 0.5, 0. , 0.5],
       [0. , 0. , 1. , 0. ]])
```

That inplace column_scale is simple:

```
def inplace_csr_column_scale(X, scale):
    # ....
    X.data *= scale.take(X.indices, mode='clip')
```

The `m_m.multiply(s_m)` step can also be done this way as well:

```
In [380]: m1_m = m_m.tocsr()
In [381]: sklearn.utils.sparsefuncs.inplace_csr_column_scale(m1_m,s_m.A1)
In [382]: m1_m.A
Out[382]: 
array([[ 0., 50.,  0., 10.],
       [12.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [12., 50.,  0., 10.],
       [ 0.,  0., 62.,  0.]])
```

I suspect the code can be cleaned up, removing the transpose etc.

Is `G` inherently square?   I like to use non-square arrays to better keep track of shapes, transposes, and dimensional sums.  I tried to expand `G` to (5,4), and hit a problem at the `s*m` step.

Comment: Thanks very much for this. It has got me over some parts of the problem. Unfortunately, it seems that both `sm_m.multiply(1 / sm_m.sum(axis=0))` and `sm_m.multiply( sm_m / sm_m.sum(axis=0))` use .todense internally, so I run out of memory.

Comment: `scikit-learn` has some faster `sparse` utility code that might help you, e.g http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.normalize.html.  I haven't used myself.

Comment: I found in `sklearn` a `inplace_csr_column_scale` function that can perform the two scaling multipications.

Comment: Thanks a lot for working this out. It looked easy, but I'm not sure I'd ever have got there myself! I can make G square in any cases where it isn't, so there should be no problem there.